# How do I call javascript functions included using PHP's 'include' using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, include

I have used ajax (not jQuery, simple JavaScript) to call a php file that 'includes' another php file, which has some javascript code in it as well (there's a script block, to be specific).

Code: Javascript: (`x` is a parameter to the function that has this code)

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
    {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", "../include/ondemand.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("f=load_page&page=" + x.name);
```

ondemand.php:

```
case 'load_page':
    $path = '../include/' . $_REQUEST['page'] .'.php';
    include $path;
```

The file is included just fine. The PHP is processed as expected.

If (say) the included file has an element with the id `'any_random_id'`, the javascript code `document.getElementById` would work for that element and be able to detect it. But say it has a function called '`do_something()`' - if I try to call that function, nothing happens. It's like it's not there.

I have tried using `eval()` on the script block (by giving it an id) - in that case, the javascript executes properly, but the elements that have (say) the attribute `"onchange='do_something()'"` don't really do anything on change.

Is there a solution? If not, any other approach?

**UPDATE:** Found the solution: *iFrames*. 
Using AJAX, I call a php script to load the particular page's (with required prefixes, blah) and then add that to the src of an iFrame. That does the job. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `$path = '../include/' . $_REQUEST['page'] .'.php';` can I have your prod url? For... reasons? :)

Comment: It is not a good practice to have javascript added by PHP. What is the reason you want that? This way the client side code is not separated from server side as it should..I believe javascript is interpreted and then being run. After that asynchronously you call PHP that adds more javascript but I don't think you can invoke this javascript, as a promise - Either way a very bad practice.. Try preloading the scripts you want statically or using dependency injection or something like require.js. Use php for returning json's or minimal templates ..

Comment: I doubt `innerHTML` let's you parse the javascript you retrieve from your ajax call. I think there's a bit of software architecture  that should be improved here.

Comment: I have a main page that has a sidebar. Clicking on items in the sidebar should use ajax to include php files (which can have seperate javascript codes) into a main content window. That php needs processing. I could create a js file containing all the functions that would possibly be required and include it in the main page's header, but I would like only 'ondemand' javascript to be included, if possible.

Comment: By 'prod' url, if you mean product url, it's not online yet. If you mean production url, I'm not sure how to answer you. :P

Comment: @Michail, I'm taking a look at require.js. Thanks. Will update in a bit. As for using php for returning json's, it's not just data that I'm dealing with. It's ... well, functions and html.

Comment: you shouldn't be returning behavior(functions) only templates + data/json

Comment: as a solution, i can have - for a page called x.php a file called x.js, let php include the former and then let the javascript that used ajax to include that file 'require', 'append' or do something similar for the latter. Um, not good?

Comment: can you give a detailed description of your use case in your post? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to parse the AJAX results into an object using `.responseXML` then you can run the results of that through a function to create the elements using `document.createElement()`. Event-related attributes will obviously need to be given their own functions, but you can `eval()` the contents of the event-related attributes as-well as the contents of the script elements. You need to be absolutely certain that the AJAX response is 100% XML-standards-compliant or it will not work.

[W3Schools: XML Parser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. If that does work (I guess it will), I'm sure it'll be very friendly with the whole concept of 'performance'. Thank you, though. Gotta try. I'll update in a few ... hours.

Comment: Sorry for the punctuality. :P